# React update state one step behind

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-state, react-state-management

So my intention is everytime I clicked the next page arrow the state would update the page number and call getData() to get data from remote database and then update work_orders in the state. But the problem is the state does not update immediately: it is always one step behind. I have tried a lot of solution from googling, but nothing works. Wondering if anyone know how to solve this problem? could redux or hooks solve this problem?

Thanks.

p.s: sorry the code looks a little messy, I have tried too many things.

```js
export default class TableList extends React.Component {
    state = {
      work_orders:[],
      // search : "",
      URL : 'http://localhost:8000/api/',
      query: {
        paginate : {
          page: 1,
          pageSize: 20,
          totalPage: 0,
          totalRows: 0,
          startIndex: 0,
          endIndex: 0,
        },
        condition: [],
        sorting: {
          id: 0,
          order: "ASC",
        },
        search: "",
        columns: [ 
        { title: 'WOID', field: 'WOID', type: 'numeric'},
        { title: 'Quantity', field: 'quantity', type: 'numeric'},
        { title: 'Order Status', field: 'orderStatus', },
        { title: 'Start Date', field: 'startDate', },
        {title: 'End Date', field: 'endDate', }],
      },
    }
   
  handleSearchChange =(text)=>{
    this.setState(prevState=>({
      query:{
        ...prevState.query,
        search: text,
      }
    }));
    console.log('query search is' + this.state.query.search);
    this.getData();
  }

  componentDidMount(prevProps, prevState, snapshot){
    console.log("did mount");
    this.getData();
  }
  // static getDerivedStateFromProps(){
  //   this.getData();

  // }

  getData=()=>{
    console.log('IN getDate');
    var url = this.state.URL + 'test?'
    var query = this.state.query;
    console.log("page is: " +  this.state.query.paginate.page);
    Axios.post( url, query).then(result=>{
      console.log("page is: " +  this.state.query.paginate.page);
      var pagi = result.data.pop();
      console.log("pagi is " + pagi.page);
      this.setState(prevState=>({
        query:{
          ...prevState.query,
          paginate:{
            ...prevState.query.paginate,
            totalRows: pagi.totalRows,
            totalPage: pagi.totalPage,
            startIndex: pagi.startIndex,
            endIndex: pagi.endIndex,
          }
      }}))
      this.setState({work_orders: [...result.data]});

  })}

componentDidUpdate(){
  
}

shouldComponentUpdate(){
  return true;
}

  handleFilterChange=(id_, val_)=>{
    var fl = false;
    if(this.state.query.condition.flag == false){
      fl = true;
    }
    this.setState(prevState=>({
        ...prevState,
        query:{
          ...prevState.query,
          condition: [
            ...prevState.query.condition,
            {id: id_, val: val_}
          ]
          }
        }
    ))
    this.getData();
    console.log(this.state);
    // this.getData()
}

// componentDidUpdate(){
//   this.getData();
// }

handleNextButtonClick= () =>{
  console.log("in handle next");
  this.setState((prevState, props)=>{ 
    return{
      ...prevState,      
      query:{
        ...prevState.query,
        paginate: {
          ...prevState.query.paginate,
          page: prevState.query.paginate.page + 1,
        }
        }
      }
    }
  );
    console.log('page is ' + this.state.query.paginate.page);
    this.getData();
}

handlePrevButtonClick=()=>{
  this.setState(prevState=>({        
    ...prevState,
    query:{
      ...prevState.query,
      paginate: {
        ...prevState.query.paginate,
        page: prevState.query.paginate.page - 1,
      }
      }
    }))
    this.getData();
}

handleFirstButtonClick=()=>{
  this.setState(prevState=>({        
    ...prevState,
    query:{
      ...prevState.query,
      paginate: {
        ...prevState.query.paginate,
        page: 1,
        startIndex: 0,
        endIndex: prevState.query.paginate.pageSize
      }
    }
  }))
    this.getData();
}

handleLastButtonClick=()=>{
  this.setState(prevState=>({        
    ...prevState,
    query:{
      ...prevState.query,
      paginate: {
        ...prevState.query.paginate,
        page: prevState.query.paginate.totalPage,
      }
    }
  }))
  this.getData();
}

render(){
  console.log(this.state.work_orders);
    return (
      <div>  
      <MaterialTable
       options={{
         sorting: true,
         filtering: false,
         search: true,
         exportButton: true,
         pageSize: 20,
         pageSizeOptions: [5, 20, 50, 100],
         thirdSortClick: true,
         initialPage: 0,
         debounceInterval: 500,
         paging: true,
       }}
 
       // data = {this.state.work_orders}
       columns={this.state.query.columns}
       data={this.state.work_orders}
      title="Work Orders"
       components={{
         Toolbar: props => (<MTableToolbar
                     {...props}
                     ref={ref => (this.child = ref)}
                     setState={state => this.setState(state)}
                     onSearchChanged={debounce((searchtext) => {
                         console.log('the text is: ' + searchtext);
                        //  const query = {...this.child.state.query}
                        //  this.child.setState({searchText: text});
                      this.handleSearchChange(searchtext);
                     }, 500)}

                 />),

        Pagination: props => (<CustomPagination
                    {...props}
                    rowsPerPage = {this.state.query.paginate.pageSize}
                    pageIndex = {this.state.query.paginate.page}
                    count = {this.state.query.paginate.totalPage}
                    rows={this.state.query.paginate.totalRows}
                    startIndex={this.state.query.paginate.startIndex}
                    endIndex={this.state.query.paginate.endIndex}
                    handleNextButtonClick={this.handleNextButtonClick}
                    handlePrevButtonClick={this.handlePrevButtonClick}
                    handleFirstButtonClick={this.handleFirstButtonClick}
                    handleLastButtonClick={this.handleLastButtonClick}
                    />)
     }}
     />
    </div>
   );
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
function CustomPagination (props){

  const handleNextButtonClick=()=>{
    props.handleNextButtonClick();
  }
  
  const handlePrevButtonClick=()=>{
    props.handlePrevButtonClick();
  }

  
  const handleFirstButtonClick=()=>{
    props.handleFirstButtonClick();
  }
  
  const handleLastButtonClick=()=>{
    props.handleLastButtonClick();
  }
return(
  <div style={{
              display: 'grid',
              paddingTop: '10px',
              gridTemplateColumns: '15% 25% 20% 25% 15%'
            }}>
    <Tooltip title={'FirstPage'}>
      <span >
        <IconButton color="primary" onClick={handleFirstButtonClick} style={{float: 'left'}} >
          <FirstPageIcon fontSize="large"   />
        </IconButton>
      </span>
    </Tooltip>
    <Tooltip title={'PrevPage'} >
      <span>
        <IconButton color="primary" onClick={handlePrevButtonClick} style={{float: 'left'}} >
          <NavigateBeforeIcon fontSize="large"  />
        </IconButton>
      </span>
    </Tooltip>

    <span>
      <p style={{
      paddingBottom: '5px',
      paddingTop: '5px',
      marginBottom: '0',
      marginTop: '0',
      // backgroundColor: 'blue',
      textAlign: 'center',
    }}>{props.startIndex} to {props.endIndex} from {props.rows}
      </p>
    </span>
    <Tooltip title={'NextPage'}>
      <span>
        <IconButton color="primary" style={{float: 'right'}} onClick={handleNextButtonClick}>
          <NavigateNextIcon fontSize="large"   />
        </IconButton>
      </span>
    </Tooltip>
    <Tooltip title={'LastPage'} >
      <span>
        <IconButton color="primary" style={{float: 'right'}}  onClick={handleLastButtonClick}>
          <LastPageIcon fontSize="large"  />
        </IconButton>
      </span>
    </Tooltip>      
</div>
);
}

export default CustomPagination;
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide details of how you're managing your state. That's where the problem will be. On another note, you can probably call the functions from props directly, instead of wrapping them here.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to copy the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the state change will happen asynchronously after the execution of the current function.
A possible solution is to use a callback function as a second argument to setState, which forces the callback to be called after the state change:

```
handleSearchChange = (text) => {
  this.setState(
    prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      query:{
        ...prevState.query,
        search: text,
      }
    }), 
    () => {
      console.log('query search is' + this.state.query.search);
      this.getData();
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your generous answer, it worked!!!! I know this might not be the proper way to implement this kind of component. What is the proper way to implement this? use function and react hook instead?

Comment: @Chase Classes are still fine to use. It's recommended to learn hooks api at some point, for future react features.